# MongoDB does not allow duplicating arrays across documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, duplicates, document

So the problem is when I have an array in a document with no values ( is empty []) and when I add another document with an array which does not contain any elements - I face this error message:

Failed to insert document.
Error:

> Error when saving document: E11000 duplicate key error collection:
>   package.package index: collection_name dup key: { : undefined }

How do I allow duplicating values in different arrays across documents?

Comment: in your schema unique:true, remove it.

Comment: Can u share ur schema?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that the array was indexed before and the setting stayed, even though it was recently removed. Simple command db.collection.getIndexes() displayed the index and db.collection.dropIndex("idxName") removed it. Currently the error does not get displayed anymore and I can now add duplicating values across documents.